# Is the empty set equal to a set containing a single tuple made up of two empty sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is { } the same as { ( {},{}) } ?

In other words if I have a set containing a single tuple, made up of two empty sets, can this be simplified top the empty set ?

Comment: Is it empty? ${}{}$

Comment: @vonbrand That's the question? Is a set containing a tuple of two nothings equal to a set of nothing?

Comment: A set containg *anything* isn't empty...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it helps. . .

. . . you can think of a (non-empty) set as a box containing objects, the empty set as a box containing nothing, and an ordered pair $(a,b)$ as an object $a$ sitting on top of an object $b$.  Then

> $\{\}$ is an empty box;

and

> $\{( \{\}, \{\} ) \}$ is a box containing an empty box sitting on another empty box.

These are not the same.

Comment: +1 for the section "sitting on" - why isn't it an empty box sitting next to another empty box?

Comment: @whytheq, because $(a, b) \ne (b, a)$, David is trying to keep that distinction

Comment: @vonbrand I really like the empty box visual

Comment: @vonbrand, thanks for the explanation, that was exactly what I intended.

Answer (score 1):

No, since the set $$\{( \{\}, \{\} ) \}$$ contains an element, namely the tuple $(\{\}, \{\})$. Since it contains an element, it's not the empty set.

In fact, you can think of this tuple as a set of sets, by (one of the usual definitions) that $(A, B) = \{A, \{A, B\}\}$; hence $\{(\{\}, \{\})\}$ is a set whose single element is a set containing two elements: The empty set, and a set containing more sets.